# Why does calling a templated method overloaded in the derived class result in a compilation error when using the base class' method signature?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a variadic method in a class called `Base`, which I overload in `Derived`. Calling the method of `Base` by using some variation of parameters not defined in `Derived` results in an error. Why?

Here is a working example:

```
struct Base
{
    template <typename... Args>
    void fun1(const Args&...) {}

    template <typename... Args> 
    void fun2(const Args&...) {}
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    void fun1(int a) {}
};

int main() {
    Derived d;

    d.fun1(1); // Pass
    d.fun2(1,2); // Pass

    d.fun1(1,2); // Fail. Why?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Derived::fun1` hides `Base::fun1`.

Comment: Try `d.Base::fun1(1,2);`

Comment: To unhide the method, you can add `using Base::fun1;` to the Derived class.